# Building Apache Nifi - Missing SNMP nar

Tags: maven-3, apache-nifi

I am trying to build Apache Nifi locally on my Windows machine by following instructions given here: https://nifi.apache.org/quickstart.html.

Running into the following issue:

> Failed to execute goal on project nifi-snmp-nar: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.apache.nifi:nifi-snmp-nar:nar:0.7.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact org.apache.nifi:nifi-snmp-processors:jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT in apache.snapshots (http://repository.apache.org/snapshots) -> [Help 1]
>   Did anyone come across the same and is there a way to by-pass this?

Answer (score 2):

The SNMP bundle was added to the 0.x branch of Apache NiFi with the versions set at 1.0.0, which is the version on the master branch. I just pushed a commit to the 0.x branch to set the versions to 0.7.0. I was able to do a clean build with an empty Maven repository, let us know if this does not resolve the problem.